# CosmosDB Change the Change Feed Processor Name

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-changefeed

I have a change feed processor:

```
var changeFeedProcessor = monitoredContainer
    .GetChangeFeedProcessorBuilder<Model>("original-processor-name", HandleChangesAsync)
        .WithInstanceName(Environment.MachineName)
        .WithLeaseContainer(leaseContainer)
        .Build();
```

`HandleChangesAsync()` is getting too big and failures are no longer well isolated. I'd like to break this into multiple processors, ie "new-processor-name-1" and "new-processor-name-2", but I'm not sure how to go about it in such a way that the new processors will not re-process all of the existing documents from the beginning.

Is there any way to have the new processors start off where the original one left off?

Comment: Does this help : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/cosmosdb?view=azure-dotnet#code-example

Comment: @jdweng Not that I can tell. Is there something specific there you're referring to that might help?

Comment: The code examples.

Comment: @jdweng I don't think either code example shows how to rename or split out a feed processor. Thanks

Comment: What is you client?

Comment: Does the below response help?

Answer (score 1):

You can create one more `changeFeedProcessor` and write it's own `HandleChangesAsync` method. Also note that you can give same `Lease prefix` and same `Lease container` in it's setting to ensure that these both processors work according to each other's checkpoints (if that is what you are trying to achieve), otherwise if you want both processors to work individually with their own checkpointing, you can have separate Lease prefixes for them.